# define newline in autocorrect of libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and want to define `new line` in `AutoCorrect` of LibreOffice.

In `LibreOffice 5.1.6.2` I selected `tools -> Autocorrect -> Autocorrect options -> replace tab` then in `Replace` field I wrote "`<ol>`" and in `With` field wrote `<ol>\n</ol>` then selected `New -> OK`. Now when I write `<ol>` and press <kbd>Space</kbd>, `LibreOffice` writes `<ol>\n</ol>` instead of:

```
<ol>
</ol>
```

How I can define `new line character` in `Autocorrect` of `LibreOffice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, using the answer in [this link](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/74940/autocorrect-text-only-greyed-out-in-all-writer-calc-etc/).

First type the *replacement* text in your document and select it:

```
<ol>
</ol>
```

Then go into `AutoCorrect Options...` and you will see your selected text as replacement (though the `NewLine` will appear as a space). You will also note that `Text only` is unchecked.

Now add your trigger text and save the new entry.

[image: AutoCorrect entry]

The AutoCorrect function will now work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers to similar questions on the official LibreOffice Forum. Namely [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/20303/find-new-line/) and [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6418/how-may-i-identify-the-line-returncarriage-return-in-writer/), these also cover this in more detail.
According to the links you need to put `^$` or `\n` into the replacement field. But you could also presumably copy-paste a line-break from a document into the replacement field, that's at least what worked for me most of the times.

Comment: Oh sorry, this clause is wrong there. You are totally correct, you can't activate regex in "Autocorrect". But `*sometext*` is possible to use as regex there.